# Simplex code in R

Tags: simplex

im trying to develop an algorithm that would take in a few x,y coordinates and then out put them in order of closest to furthest(from origin), I cant use the library for the simplex function, just need some help with the logic.

Comment: Show us what you have so far and we can help you improve it but you'll likely find very little interest from people here to write the code for you.  Check out [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I mean i just want logic more than code, like I was thinking of using a knn function but wasnt sure how the parameters would work,like lets say i have 4 (x,y) coordinates so I just wanna know which is the closest to the origin and then which is the next closest to point 1 and so on